# Pandas to_sql to add rows to database. Error: [ODBC SQL Server Driver] Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have the following dataframe that I would like to use to insert rows into Microsoft SQL Server

```
new_companies = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Id","Name","CreatedDate","ModifiedDate","IsActive","No","SIMSId"])
# Insert two rows
new_companies = new_companies.append({
  "Id":999999,
  "Name":"Unknown",
  "CreatedDate": Timestamp('19010101'),
  "ModifiedDate": Timestamp('19010101'),
  "IsActive":0,
  "No":"999999",
  "SIMSId":""
}, ignore_index=True)
new_companies = new_companies.append({
  "Id":17,
  "Name":"Acme",
  "CreatedDate": Timestamp('20210228'),
  "ModifiedDate": Timestamp('20210228'),
  "IsActive":0,
  "No":"999999",
  "SIMSId":""
}, ignore_index=True)

new_companies.info()

# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   Id            2 non-null      object        
 1   Name          2 non-null      object        
 2   CreatedDate   2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 3   ModifiedDate  2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 4   IsActive      2 non-null      object        
 5   No            2 non-null      object        
 6   SIMSId        2 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(5)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

I then create a database connection in the following way and attempt to insert the rows:

```
import sqlalchemy

conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://*myserver*/*mydatabase?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server",echo=False,fast_executemany=True)

new_companies.to_sql('Companies',con=conn,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO [Companies] ([Id], [Name], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedDate], [IsActive], [No], [SIMSId]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ((999999, 'Unknown', datetime.datetime(1901, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1901, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0, '999999', ''), (17, 'Acme', datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 28, 0, 0), 0, '999', '0E581100-80E4-4024-86DF-072739F50FA8'))]
```

Here is the table definition from SQL Managaement Tools

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [No] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SIMSId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It is hard for me to diagnose that the two datetimes are the problem (i.e. I am not sure they are the problem) but I am hoping someone can help me diagnose and fix the issue.

Comment: I think `Timestamp('20210228')` is not acceptable, convert it to a string, e.g. `2021-02-28`

Comment: can you show the table definitions as well ? also you haven't specified a schema are you writing to `dbo`?

Comment: Is `SIMSId` a GUID column?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, SIMSId is a GUID and references an external system.

Comment: @Manakin I have included the table definition. I will try adding the 'dbo' schema.

Comment: `''` (empty string) is not a valid GUID. If you want null, pass null, if you want a zero GUID, pass that

Comment: @Charlieface I will try setting the empty string GUID to np.NAN (sets it to NULL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the change I made to get this working:

- Changed the empty string to np.NAN for the SIMSId GUID

After these changes, I received errors about IDENTITY_ISERT being turned off, so I had to add the lines to turn it on and then off again. If I was not directly inserting the key, I would not need this step.

Here is my final code:

```
# Setup dataframe with columns
new_companies = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Id","Name","CreatedDate","ModifiedDate","IsActive","No","SIMSId"])
# Insert two rows
new_companies = new_companies.append({
  "Id":999999,
  "Name":"Unknown",
  "CreatedDate": Timestamp('19010101'),
  "ModifiedDate": Timestamp('19010101'),
  "IsActive":0,
  "No":"999999",
  "SIMSId":np.NAN
}, ignore_index=True)
new_companies = new_companies.append({
  "Id":17,
  "Name":"Acme",
  "CreatedDate": Timestamp('20210228'),
  "ModifiedDate": Timestamp('20210228'),
  "IsActive":0,
  "No":"999999",
  "SIMSId":np.NAN
}, ignore_index=True)

# Connect to database and enable direct insert of ID values
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://*myserver*/*mydatabase?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server",echo=False)

command = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Companies ON"
engine.execute(command)

new_companies.to_sql('Companies',con=engine,if_exists='append',index=False)

command = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Companies OFF"
engine.execute(command)
```

Comment: You should not be inserting into identity fields, especially if used as PK. Let DB generate values. Drop the column before `to_sql`.

Comment: @Parfait That would be ideal, yes. In my case, I needed to create the ID in code and could not rely on the database.